# URL displays different page (a loop)?

Tags: urls

So I've been playing with many themes lately and finally came back to my old one, and I'm in trouble.

I have (always had actually) a page called Portfolio. It's address is www.example.com/portfolio. I have a few different pages such as Contact at www.example.com/contact etc.

Now, the problem is, when I go to www.example.com/portfolio it displays a loop from my custom post type called portfolio but not the page itself. Even when I open the page using direct link from wp-admin, it still displays wrong content.

After I delete any page and I try to access it I get 404 page, but after I delete Portfolio there's still this loop under example.com/portfolio :O

I'm pretty sure /portfolio URL has been hardcoded somehow in my database by one of the previous themes (is it even possible?) and now points to something else. How to fix that?

Comment: A (public) CPT named `portfolio` will have an archive page at `www.example.com/portfolio`. Sounds like things are working as they should be. You need to explain things a bit more.

Comment: This is strange, because it never had before... I have multiple other public CPTs and they don't have any archive pages as well, also I never set has_archive for register_post_types, any idea how to fix it then?

Comment: Okay, checked the theme on different WP install and /portfolio returns 404 as expected. Still no idea how to fix that.

Comment: It depends on how you register the CPT. You _can_ register them with arguments such that there is no archive, but I am pretty sure that the default is to have an archive page.

Comment: I'm aware of that, the point is, the archive was set to false. I'm not sure what to do next, reinstalling would totally help but it's going to take forever (reuploading all the pictures and setting them as featured images etc.), eh.

Comment: Sorry. I don't know how to guess what is wrong with your install. I assume you've reset permalinks?

Comment: Yes, I did, no luck. The point is it's nothing wrong with the install, it happened after activating multiple different themes. I will try to figure it own on my own and will let you know how it went.